# Boost log severity_logger init_from_stream

Tags: c++, logging, boost, boost-log

I am using boost 1.54.0.
Below you can find a minimum example that illustrates my problem.

I use the severity_logger of boost log.
I want to configure my sinks from a stream.
(In the following example I use a stringstream.
In my real application the stream comes from a file.)
I want to use the %Severity% for output or filtering purposes.

My **problem** is: If I use it as given in the example below, **%Severity% is empty.**

%LineID% and %Message% are filled as expected.
If I set up a sink as given in the outcommented lines, it works as expected.

Any ideas?

```
#include <boost/log/sources/severity_logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/common_attributes.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/from_stream.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/console.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>

enum SeverityLevel { trace, fatal };

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    boost::log::add_common_attributes();
    /*
    struct severity_tag;
    boost::log::add_console_log(std::clog,
        boost::log::keywords::format = (
            boost::log::expressions::stream
                << boost::log::expressions::attr< unsigned int >("LineID")
                << ": <" << boost::log::expressions::attr<SeverityLevel, severity_tag >("Severity")
                << "> " << boost::log::expressions::smessage)
    ); */

    std::stringstream s;
    s << "[Sinks.MySink]" << std::endl;
    s << "Destination=Console" << std::endl;
    s << "Format=\"%LineID%: <%Severity%> - %Message%\"" << std::endl;
    boost::log::init_from_stream(s);

    boost::log::sources::severity_logger<SeverityLevel> lg;
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, trace) << "This is a trace message";
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, fatal) << "This is a fatal message";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would appeat that you need to instruct Boost Log to actually use `Sinks.MySink`. Sadly, I have no experience with Boost Log configuration

Comment: That is not the problem. It is using MySink. The Format I provide is used as wanted. Except: %Severity% is replaced by an empty string. It should be the number of the enum value. It works out fine with the outcommented way of sink configuration.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are right. This is a known bug and fixed in the current development version.

Here is the bug report: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/8840

To make this answer less dependent on the link here is the way it was resolved within the report:

> You need to register your severity attribute in the library before parsing the settings file. See [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/extension/settings.html#log.extension.settings.adding_support_for_user_defined_types_to_the_formatter_parser). The attribute may have to be registered both for formatter and filter parsers, if you want to filter records based on severity level.
>
> OK, this is working but I had to add a stream input/extraction function and then I had to add the following two lines before loading the settings from the settings file:

```
logging::register_simple_formatter_factory<ESeverityLevel, char>("Severity");
logging::register_simple_filter_factory<ESeverityLevel, char>("Severity");
```

Comment: You're the man. Took me 2 days until I stumbled upon your post because I believed I had made a config-mistake...

Comment: Few years later... Boost is version 1.62 and I was hitting the same issue in the last 2 days. Thanks to this answer I was able to make the "Severity" working.